# Group rows using the cumulative sum of a third column

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a table with two columns:

- sort_column = A column I use for sorting
- value_column = My metric of interest (a positive integer)

Using SQL, I need to create contiguous groups of rows, ordered by sort_column, such that the sum of value_column within each group is the largest possible but staying below 100 (100 not included).

Find below an example of my desired result.

Thanks

| sort_column | value_column | desired_result |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 53 | 1 |
| 2 | 25 | 1 |
| 3 | 33 | 2 |
| 4 | 25 | 2 |
| 5 | 10 | 2 |
| 6 | 46 | 3 |
| 7 | 9 | 3 |
| 8 | 49 | 4 |
| 9 | 48 | 4 |
| 10 | 53 | 5 |
| 11 | 33 | 5 |
| 12 | 52 | 6 |
| 13 | 29 | 6 |
| 14 | 16 | 6 |
| 15 | 66 | 7 |
| 16 | 1 | 7 |
| 17 | 62 | 8 |
| 18 | 57 | 9 |
| 19 | 47 | 10 |
| 20 | 12 | 10 |

Comment: how big (or small) your table?

Comment: Quite large (several GB). Is that relevant?

Comment: Can you elaborate more on your use case? Would it be okay to use something other than BigQuery to attain your desired result?

Comment: yes - size always matter :o) so, let me come from different angle  - how many rows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so after a  few lengthy attempts, I came to the conclusion the task is impossible with pure SQL, because a given value of the desired column depends on previous values of that same column, in a way that cannot be obtained from the first two columns alone, so the problem is impossible to tackle without using a recursive CTE, which BigQuery does not support.

I solved the issue by writing a javascript UDF for the task. It seems to be working fine and produces the expected results.

Many thanks everyone!